# Fix a shared image description on LinkedIn post?

Tags: html, image, linkedin-api, blogs

The company I work for would like to share links to our blog posts from the company website onto our company LinkedIn. While we'd love to do it Twitter's way (large image on an embedded link), LinkedIn doesn't seem to have that capability. So, we opted to, for some pieces, have a link and separately upload the image.

However, when someone shares the image, the following is what they see (using Dropbox as an example as it seems they have the issue as well):

[image]

We don't like that the file's name is what shows, and were wondering if there is a way, either in the HTML on our blog site or in LinkedIn settings, to change by default what appears as the title there for sharing, so that users don't have to click the Edit button to have it say something more preferable.

Any ideas, LinkedIn community?

Answer (score 2):

There are some meta tags to customize LinkedIn sharing. You can add the following meta tags to your post. So, you can customize title, description and image.

```
<!-- Title of share -->
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the page'/>

<!-- Image -->
<meta property='og:image' content='http://yourdomain.com/test.jpg'/>

<!-- Description -->
<meta property='og:description' content='Description of the page'/>

<!-- URL -->
<meta property='og:url' content='http://www.example.com/URL of the article'/>
```

Comment: I don't get why content attribute's value for each of these meta tags starts with single quote and ends with double.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the information related to the image (i.e. title, description) when you create a share using the API.

This is accomplished with an API call that looks like:

**POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json**

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
    "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

Official docs available here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: This doesn't dispaly the description.